# Agrupar itens dentro de um foreach

Tags: c#

Tenho um objeto que me traz uma cesta com vários itens. Preciso dentro de um foreach agrupar os itens por natureza de operação. Como eu faço isso?

Será algo mais ou menos assim:

```
Prod: 2345
Nat. Oper: 5402

Prod: 2343
Nat. Oper: 5402

Prod: 46123
Nat. Oper: 5404
```

Como eu agrupo? No exemplo acima teria dois grupos.

Comment: Se tem algum código?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, não tenho. Isso é algo novo a implementar e ainda não sei como fazer.

Comment: Você quer uma resposta genérica então?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, isso mesmo

Comment: Se poderia dizer na sua pergunta da onde vem os dados e porque do foreach

Comment: O foreach é para um insert por produto. Os dados vem de uma proc através de um serviço. Cara tô perdido aqui.

Comment: E o que você quer dizer com agrupar?

Answer (score 1):

Com uma estrutura simples você e utilizando o LINQ (System.Linq) você pode resolver esse problema da seguinte forma:

Crie uma estrutura para armazenar os seus grupos

```
public class NaturezaOperacao
{
    public int NatOper { get; set; }
    public List<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

    public NaturezaOperacao()
    {
        //Inicialiando a lista para evitar problemas de null reference;
        Produtos = new List<Produto>();
    }
}
```

E vamos chamar o seu objeto de entrada como Produto e representá-lo da seguinte forma.

```
public class Produto
{
    public int Prod { get; set; }
    public int NatOper { get; set; }
}
```

Agora vem o `Linq` e um `foreach()` para você agrupar os produtos por `NatOper`

```
//Sua lista de entrada
var produtosInput = new List<Produto>
{
    new Produto { Prod = 2345, NatOper = 5402 },
    new Produto { Prod = 2343, NatOper = 5402 },
    new Produto { Prod = 46123, NatOper = 5404 }
};

var gruposNaturezaOperacao = new List<NaturezaOperacao>();

//Selecionando as NatOper distintas que que existem na entrada
foreach (var natureza in produtosInput.Select(n => n.NatOper).Distinct())
{
    gruposNaturezaOperacao.Add(new NaturezaOperacao
    {
        NatOper = natureza,
        Produtos = produtosInput.Where(p => p.NatOper == natureza).ToList()
    });
}
```

O resultado final para `gruposNaturezaOperacao`, representado em JSON para facilitar a visualização, será:

```
[
   {
      "NatOper":5402,
      "Produtos":[
         {
            "Prod":2345,
            "NatOper":5402
         },
         {
            "Prod":2343,
            "NatOper":5402
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "NatOper":5404,
      "Produtos":[
         {
            "Prod":46123,
            "NatOper":5404
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando dicionários você consegue realizar esse agrupamento tranquilamente.

Exemplo:

```
Dictionary<Int32, List<Produto>> dicionárioDeNaturezas = new  Dictionary<Int32,List<Produto>>(); 

foreach(var umProduto in produtos)
{
    if(dicionárioDeNaturezas.ContainsKey(umProduto.NaturezaId)
    {
        if(dicionárioDeNaturezas[umProduto.NaturezaId].SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(umProduto.id) == null)
        {
             dicionárioDeNaturezas[umProduto.NaturezaId].Add(umProduto);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dicionárioDeNaturezas.Add(umProduto.NaturezaId, new List<Produto>());
        dicionárioDeNaturezas[umProduto.NaturezaId].Add(umProduto);
    }
}
```

Assim você tem todos os produtos agrupados por naturza de operação. No exemplo eu usei o ID da natureza, mas você pode utilizar o object NaturezaDeOperação também.