# Trazer mais um campo em group by linq

Tags: c#

Tenho isso

```
var grupo = from item in aliquotaProduto
group item by item.CFOP_ID into agrupamento
select new
{
    Categoria = agrupamento.Key,
    Quantidade = agrupamento.Count()
};
```

consigo trazer um ID_PROD no select além de Categoria e Quantidade?

**EDIT1**

Fiz assim

```
var grupo = from item in aliquotaProduto
    group item by item.CFOP_ID into agrupamento
    select new
    {
        Produto = agrupamento.Select(it => it.ID_PROD), 
        Categoria = agrupamento.Key,
        Quantidade = agrupamento.Count()
    };
```

mas estou com dificuldade de trabalhar com ele. Eu tenho os Produtos corretos, mas não consigo fazer mais nada com eles. Como eu faço isso? Como eu atribuo agora o meu rateio?

**EDIT2**

se eu faço assim

```
var grupo = from item in objectProd
group item by new { item.CFOP_ID, item.ID_Prod };
```

eu tenho isso

```
Key = {{CFOP_ID = 5402, ID_PRO = 1 }} 
Key = {{CFOP_ID = 5404, ID_PRO = 2 }} 
Key = {{CFOP_ID = 5404, ID_PRO = 3 }}
```

se faço isso:

```
foreach(var item in Lista)
{
    item.vlrUnit = rateio * varCount;

//a varCount deveria vir 1 para CFOP = 5402 e 2 para CFOP = 5404. É isso que eu não sei fazer.
}
```

é exatamente isso que eu preciso fazer.

Comment: duvido que funcione, mas tentou adicionar um `.ToList()` no final?
`agrupamento.Select(it => it.ID_PROD).ToList()`

Comment: O problema, @LeandroAngelo, é exatamente funcionar e não sei como fazer e tenho que fazer, entende.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, então dentro de produto eu tenho dois itens. Um prod com 5402 e quantidade = 1 e outro com dois prod com 5404 e quantidade = 2. Não consigo chegar no item [1] com os dois prods. Tá difícil até explicar.

Comment: você fez essa mesma pergunta de outra forma antes, viu minha resposta? Não quis seguir por aquela linha?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, talvez eu não tenha conseguido explicar elhor minha dúvida. O seguinte: Eu tenho 3 itens. Esses itens eu agrupo por cfop. Logo esse agrupamento deu dois registros. Um item com 5402 e dois com 5404. Eu preciso pegar o meu rateio e multiplicar por esses counts(1 e 2) de forma que no fina eu tenha: O registro 1 multiplicado por 1 e os outros dois registros multiplicado por 2. Acontece que meu foreach tem 3 itens e se eu faço um foreach dentro do outro foreach com os itens agrupados, ele só vai percorre duas vezes e o terceiro item não será multiplicado.

Comment: Você ainda enfrentará o mesmo problema... Faça o foreach no agrupamento e a multiplicação pelo Count de produtos
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288656/agrupar-itens-dentro-de-um-foreach/288770#288770

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente o seguinte.:

```
var quantidades = (
    from item in objectProd 
    group item.CFOP_ID by item.CFOP_ID
).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count())

foreach(var produto in objectProd)
{
    var quantidade = quantidades[produto.CFOP_ID];
    produto.vlrUnit = rateio * quantidade;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma [pergunta semelhante](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns) no SOEN e segundo ela basta colocar os campos direto no *group by*:

```
var grupo = from item in aliquotaProduto
group item by new { item.CFOP_ID, item.CAMPO_CATEGORIA, item.CAMPO_QTD }
```

Comment: rLinhares, da forma acima eu não consigo agrupar, eu tenho três linhas, pois são 3 produtos diferentes. O que eu quero é se eu tenho dois CFOP iguais, eu somo isso e multiplico pelo rateio. Isso é que eu não estou sabendo fazer.